# error code handle not working

Tags: error-handling, swift3, xcode8

I am working on a tutorial, the person is using swift 2 Xcode 7 and firebase.

her has an error handler so that when it returns a code it progresses to the next step.

When I try it it won't allow the syntax error.code, so that it returns the error code -8 when a user is not registered.

below is the code is there another way to do this, I tried (error as! NSError).

all the best
Tony Merritt

```
if error != nil {
            print(error)

            if error.code == STATUS_ACCOUNT_NONEXIST {
                FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out with help from another post.

I changed the code to.

```
    if error != nil {

        print(error)


        let code = (error as! NSError).code

        if code == STATUS_ACCOUNT_NONEXIST
```

STATUS_ACCOUNT_NONEXIST was set with a value of 17011 in a different area.